# SQL query keeps telling me I am missing a right parenthesis but I am not

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

Can anyone see what is wrong with this query:

```
INSERT INTO CAND_SEARCH_RESULT_IDS (csr_id, sort_seq, cand_id) 
    SELECT
        358572 csr, rownum sort_seq,
        c.cand_id 
    FROM 
        candidates c 
    WHERE 
        EXISTS (SELECT cv.cand_id 
                FROM candidate_visibility cv
                WHERE c.cand_id = cv.cand_id AND cv.client_id = 'client')
        AND c.status IN ('AP', 'UC', 'IC', 'UI')
        AND (c.client_id = 'client')
        AND (c.cand_id IN (SELECT SCORE(1) score, cand_id 
                           FROM cand_kw 
                           WHERE client_id = 'client' 
                             AND (CONTAINS(kw, 'customer service', 1) > 0)
                           ORDER BY SCORE(1) DESC));
```

It keeps telling me I am missing a right parenthesis but I am not. The issue is with the query inside the `c.cand_id` in section. If I extract :

```
    SELECT
        SCORE(1) score,
        cand_id 
    FROM
        cand_kw 
    WHERE
        client_id = 'client' 
        AND (CONTAINS(kw, 'customer service', 1) > 0)
    ORDER BY
        SCORE(1) DESC
```

it works perfectly.

I am using an old Oracle 9i database on a 20 year old application which cannot be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the order-by clause from the subquery:

```
...
and ( c.cand_id in 
     (
        SELECT
--           SCORE(1) score,
           cand_id 
        from
           cand_kw 
        WHERE
           client_id = 'client' 
           AND 
           (
              CONTAINS(kw, 'customer service', 1) > 0
           )
--        ORDER BY
--           SCORE(1) DESC 
     )
   );
```

It doesn't make sense there - it has no impact on the result of the `IN()` - and is illegal in some subqueries, depending on the context.

Because the parser knows it's illegal in this case, it is expecting to see the closing parenthesis for the subquery where you have `ORDER`. It doesn't see one there, so it throws the exception that it is missing. That error doesn't always mean that the number of left and right parentheses don't match, just that it isn't see one where it expects to.

As you pointed out, you also have to remove the `SCORE(1) score` expression and alias form the subquery. You are comparing the `c.cand_id` value with the list of values returned by that subquery; so it can only have a single column. (You can compare pairs of values but that isn't helpful here unless you're looking for a specific score).

Comment: I also have to remove SCORE(1) score, to get this query run otherwise i get the error to many values. Does this mean the contains is not ordered by score?

Comment: Yes, i didn't look beyond the initial error. The subquery is not ordered by score, no. it would make no difference - either the ID is in the list or it isn't, its position with the list is irrelevant.

Comment: @user794846: you're getting "too many values" because your subquery returns multitple values, but your IN clause only compares to a single value. As @AlexPoole said, get rid of the ORDER BY and, as you said, get rid of `SCORE(1) score` in the SELECT list, and you should be fine.